# Unable to retrieve typeArguments for reflected generic in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, reflection, dart-mirrors

I'm trying to get real types passed into generic, but I always get empty collection.

So far, to me it is mandatory to use `dart:mirrors`.

In future though I'm planning to migrate to *reflectable*.

Please hint me, where I'm wrong?

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors'

class A<T> {}

void main() {
  print(
    reflectClass(A<int>).typeArguments
  );
}
```

Output:

```
[]

Exited.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the function `reflectType`.

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A<T> {}

void main() {

  print(reflectType(A<int>).typeArguments);
}
```

Running this program in a terminal results in the following output:

```
$ dart main.dart
[ClassMirror on 'int']
```